# Is it formal to use "jump to conclusion"?

Tags: formality

Is it formal to use "jump to conclusions" in a sentence ?

e.g. We cannot jump to the conclusion that apples are all red.

Comment: It should be okay *if* you use the idiom precisely - and your example doesn't. You might get away with "We must not *jump to conclusions* and insist that all apples are red." The idiom is often used to signal a list of repercussions is forthcoming.

Comment: The phrase "jump to conclusions" is idiomatic in English and (I strongly suspect) appears in writing pitched at many different levels of formality. As Phil Sweet observes, the most important issue involved in using an idiom such as "jump to conclusions" is to express it in the normal way a native English speaker would (which in this case means using the plural form _conclusions_ and not the singular form as you do in your question title) and with its generally understood meaning (which here is essentially "reach a conclusion without adequate caution, evidence, or thought").

Comment: Jump to a conclusion in English is  not informal or formal. It means you have not thought about the subject matter in an in-depth manner. It is not the same as coming to a conclusion after giving a matter serious thought....In fact, at meetings, a person might say: Let's not jump to the conclusion that [x is true]. We need to give it serious thought.

Answer (score 2):

I think the expression is old and common enough to be able to be used either in informal as well formal contexts:

***[Jump to conclusions](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/jump-to-a-conclusion):***

> - Form an opinion or judgment hastily, as in Wait till you have the facts; don't jump to a conclusion. [c. 1700 ].

The American Heritage® Idioms Dictionary

If you check its usages in [Google Books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=jump%20to%20conclusions%2C%20come%20to%20conclusions%20&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cjump%20to%20conclusions%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccome%20to%20conclusions%3B%2Cc0) you can find its usage is formal contexts such as: 
From [Cognitive Remediation Therapy for Schizophrenia: Theory and Practice](https://books.google.it/books?id=FYOOAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA60&dq=%22jump%20to%20conclusions%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwit756lrufOAhWJzRoKHRDXAqU4ChDoAQggMAE#v=onepage&q=%22jump%20to%20conclusions%22&f=false):

> - This finding is consistent with the suggestion of a greater influence of immediate environmental stimuli in people with schizophrenia relative to the effects of prior learning; ***thus, they may jump to conclusions about the meaning of events.*** A lack of spontaneous behaviour is said to reflect avoidant coping strategies employed to ...

Answer (score 0):

T**o come to or arrive at a conclusion** means you think about something and end up with a conclusion.

**To jump to a conclusion means you did not think about something and ended up with a conclusion**.
**The two things do not mean the same thing!**

This is the kind of question that one can answer as an educated native speaker of English without recourse to dictionaries.

Comment: Yes, but OP question is not about the difference between jump and come to a conclusion.

Comment: @Josh61 The OP doesn't realize there is a difference and the difference is not formal and informal. The difference is semantic. If you jump to a conclusion in English you are not THINKING much about whatever the subject of your thoughts are. In English, you would never say JUMP to a conclusion if something is thought out properly....I mean....

Comment: fair point, but I think that the formal/informal question is reasonable, it does "sound" informal and I understand the point.

Comment: No, it is not reasonable. The question was asked because the OP doesn't know the difference between jump to a conclusion and come to a conclusion. If she had, she would not have asked the question. It has a very specific meaning and can be used in very formal situations (like a litigation brief, say) to mean not thought out in depth.

Comment: I don't know how you can say what OP knows or does not know.

Comment: Because of the question itself. It is an idiomatic way to say arrive at a conclusion hastily but that does not make it informal.

Comment: @ Lambie: Clearly you misunderstood my question, which would be explicit for an educated native speaker of English. I'm a guy not a girl too. You shouldn't jump to conclusions, or should I say, you shouldn't come to conclusions (yes I know the difference between the two....).

Comment: I am a highly educated native speaker of English and a linguist. Jump to a conclusion means to come to a conclusion hastily. It is a typical idiom and there is nothing to suggest it is informal.